# Zoom image in blackberry Torch

Tags: blackberry

I want to zoom image in blackberry torch.For this i am using ZoomScreen predefined class.It working  but my problem is i need a screen which can contain header,some text and then one image which can be zoom in and out.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZoomScreen extends MainScreen, so you can set a title and a status for it by adding setTitle() and setStatus() functions. You can use normal adds too. Did you try this and did not work?

Comment: thanks for quick reply.Setting title is working But when i am trying to add label field .It is not displaying any text

Comment: So why not adding your fields in title and status?

Comment: yes i am doing the same .But background of screen is black that i want to change to some other color is there any way .thanks

Comment: use in the constructor:
`this.getMainManager().setBackground(yourBackground);`

Comment: i am not extending the Zoomscreen class

Comment: noooo i didnt mean that. In the constructor of this class, where you write your setTitle and setStatus commands, enter this background line

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4567/discussion-between-chandan-and-farid-farhat)